# Two notions of classifying space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

Why is the categorical classifying space for  a  group  G, i.e., geometric  realization of the nerve of G(as a category  of  One object), the same as the topological classifying space for principle G bundles?

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289161/classifying-space-as-the-geometric-realization-of-the-nerve-of-g-viewed-as-a-s